# CocoaPods input/output error

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

Cocoapods 0.35.0
Xcode 6
iOS 7.0
OS X: 10.10.2

My project is stored on a network drive. When i import AFNetworking.h, i have this error:

/Volumes/iOS_Development/NewMLK/MyProject/RT_RequestManager.h:10:9: Cannot open file '/Volumes/iOS_Development/NewMLK/Pods/Headers/Public/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h': Input/output error

But if I copy My Project to OS X Folder error is disappear.